# How to create an embedded code for wordpress shortcode?

Tags: plugin-development

**What I have done**

I have a developed a custom WordPress plugin for displaying a custom calculator on my website. And regarding the same I have created a short-code for it which I am using to place it on any page of my website.

**What I want to achieve**

Now I want to create an embedded code for it so that by using that embedded code, we can place this calculator on any website. Means simply how we can create an embedded code for a short-code in WordPress.

I have an idea that we can achieve the same using iframe but still want some guidance on it.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear to your question, I'm afraid. *An embedded code*? Are you looking for something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/cOhZU8W.png) - a shortcode suggestion?

Comment: _Embedded code_ I meant to say, the code which can be placed on any website to display my custom calculator as like the embedded code provided by youtube etc.

Comment: Isn't that simple using `<code>&lt;div&gt;</code>` to show something like `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to show on 3-rd website, wich is not wordpress or isn't using your plugin than the only way is to use iframe

Aldought there might be better solutions, i would do it these way:

1. Create ajax action ( `wp_ajax_nopriv_....` )
2. in callback write the code that should echo ( your shortcode ). see example under a list
3. add some feature that will generate url and redirect it to your ajax calls, for ex. instead of `yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=iframe&arg1=test` you'll have something like `yoursite.com?blahblah` wich in `.htaccess` or `php` will redirect it to ajax url ( the first one ) [ these step is not nesseccery ]
4. Provide your visitors an link builder or something like it, so they could just copy-paste embedded code

The callback ex.:

```
$arg1 = $_GET['arg1']; // get all variables that cann be used in shortcode
?>
<html><head>....</head><body><?php echo do_shortcode( '[your_shortcode arg1="' . $arg1 . '"]' ); ?></body></html>
<?php die();
```

in head, or before `</body>` you should do `wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script' ... )` and `wp_enqueue_style( 'your_style' .. )` related to your shortcode, for their proper look atc.

And generated code ( without 3 step ) should look like these:

```
<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=iframe&arg1=test"></iframe>
```

And it should show your shortcode on every website

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the things, I have figured out that we can simply achieve it by following these steps :

1) Firstly create a WordPress page.

2) Create a separate custom page template for it and put the short-code there.

3) Remove the header (get_header) and footer (get_footer) from the page in case you want only the short-code content.

4) Create an embedded code which is basically a iframe tag having the permalink of that page as its source.

5) Provide this iframe tag/ embedded code to anyone who wants to display your WordPress short-code on their website.

Hope it helps someone else having the same requirements.